# Calculating the Output Resistance of a Widlar Current Source

Tags: bjt, resistance, current-source, output

I'm currently struggling to understand the small signal equivalent used in the following calculation:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widlar_current_source#Output_impedance

My problem is: How come they neglected the transimpedance current source of the LHS BJT (connected to R1)? When doing the calculation myself (using a slightly different way) I ended up needing it.

Regarding this question: Is there maybe a "rule of thumb" to decide when to leave out current sources in the small signal model?

Comment: I liked the discussion of current mirrors in AoE (Art of Elec.).  As noted by Andy, the first transistor is a diode connected transistor.  It basically programs the Vbe drop of the second transistor, which does all the heavy lifting.  It's the second transistor that mostly determines the impedance.  I don't know any rule of thumb, except keep it as  simple as possible.  (But no simpler :^)

Comment: "keep it as simple as possible. (But no simpler)".  This sentence reminds me on Albert Einstein.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I realize that seen from the output, one is mainly dealing with the right transistor. But why does this lead to no transconductance in the left transistor?

Answer (score 1):

The left hand transistor is configured as a diode: -

[image]

It won't have any transimpedance associated with it. Note that the collector and base are connected. See [this](https://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ee321/spring99/LECT/lect17mar12.pdf) for further info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and the linked slides. Unfortunatalely I fail to see why the diode connected transistor doesn't include any transimpedance. If one were to apply a voltage at the base (=collector) terminal, wouldn't the current increase? In our exercise class we only remarked that its purpose was to "guarantee" the transistors to be in the active region of operation.

Comment: As would the current of a diode connected in the same way. The transistor is there (configured as a diode) for a fundamental purposes all to do with current mirrors. Try looking it up. Without the transistor being there the circuit would make a really poor current mirror/source.

Comment: Thanks again for your input. The transistors are used because both of them having an equal base-emitter voltage means that the current will be copied (approx.). The diode configuration is used to guarantee the transistor to be operating in active region. Is that correct?

Comment: The diode does not guarantee that. The diode just linearises things. It's collector voltage that dictates the region.